# Specific module import, from custom Python package with separate files, but: efficient thought explicit

Tags: python, syntax, python-import, code-formatting, python-packaging

From a custom package I made I would like to be able to import only specific functions where I need them. I am able to do this, but the methods I am using for this seem too verbose and ugly. A more minimal variation is also working, but this is importing the complete package, which I prefer not to.

First, kind of ideally I wished something like this would work:

```
from custompackage as cp import firstfunction, secondfunction


cp.firstfunction()
cp.secondfunction()
```

...with the package having the following filestructure:

```
custompackage/

├──  __init__.py
│
├──  firstfunctionfile.py
│
├──  secondfunctionfile.py
│
├──  thirdfunctionfile.py
│
└──  etc.py
```

...and the function files looking like this:

*firstfunctionfile.py*

```
def firstfunction():
    print('\nThis first function file is containing this first function')
```

*secondfunctionfile.py*

```
def secondfunction():
    print('...so is this second having a second function.\n')
```

*thirdfunctionfile.py*

```
def thirdfunction():
    print('The third is not being used yet.')
```

With a different import syntax I am able to make this work, kind of, using the following two methods:

**1. Functional, importing only selected modules, but with an ugly underscore:**

```
from custompackage.firstfunctionfile import firstfunction as cp_firstfunction
from custompackage.secondfunctionfile import secondfunction as cp_secondfunction

cp_firstfunction()
cp_secondfunction()
```

(And having an empty *custompackage/__init__.py* file)

**2. Functional, aesthetical more pleasing, but importing all functions and thereby some unnecessary**

```
import custompackage as cp

cp.firstfunction()
cp.secondfunction()
```

*custompackage/__init__.py*

```
from .firstfunctionfile import firstfunction
from .secondfunctionfile import secondfunction
```

These two methods do only partially meet what I think should be possible: importing a custom package both specific and clean. I hope someone is having more knowledge about how and to what extend I would be able to get closer to something like the first mentioned fictional version, or something more neat...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Efficiency reasons? You can't avoid loading the whole module, so there's no efficiency benefit to be gained.

Comment: (`from` imports just change what names you bind. The whole module still has to be loaded, to make sure all necessary setup happens and all dependencies of the imported things are available.)

Comment: Ah, then I seem to have misunderstood that everything in the import syntax, apart from the literal ‘import’ part itself, is just about name modification. Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: Still wondering though, is the following code the most clean and minimal way of importing all functions within the directory directory when you want to use those like `cp.firstfunction()`, `cp.secondfunction()`, etc? Then within the _\_\_init\_\_.py_ file: `from .firstfunctionfile import *` and `from .secondfunctionfile import *`, etc.?